# What does 窓という窓 mean?

Tags: grammar, expressions

What does 窓という窓 mean? I found it in this sentence in Harry Potter:

> 木の扉に寄りかかってホグワーツを見上げると、窓という窓が夕日に照らされて赤くキラキラ輝いている。

Comment: Out of curiosity, where in the book is this sentence?

Comment: @snailplane it's from the first book in the series, chapter 13, right after the quiddich match. i'm not sure if there are different translations out there or not.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this exact usage with windows appears in a much older book, 燃え尽きた地図, on page 325 of the Shinshio paperback edition.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Repeating the same noun twice as in`NounというNoun` here has the meaning of "all" ([definition #5 at Daijisen](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154743/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86/)):

> …窓という窓が夕日に照らされて赤くキラキラ輝いている。
>   "...all of the windows are being shined on by the evening sun and are sparkling red."

Separately, `Time NounというTime Noun` can also emphasize time words, but that's a different usage ([definition #4 at Daijisen](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154743/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86/)), e.g.:

> 今日という今日
>   "today of all days"